# Get JSON string for my object with RestKit

Tags: ios, json, restkit, restkit-0.20

I want to create a json string to save in `NSUserDefaults` and then get it back from it.

I've already added RestKit to my project, to send and receive objects from the server.
However, now i want to flatten and save the data.

How do i use restkit to get a JSON string of my object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed the same functionality (in my case to send he JSON as a multipart attribute), so after a while searching, I get the solution.

You can get the JSON data (and JSON string) using RestKit with that code, you have to pass the object you want to convert, and the mapping you want to use to convert.

```
RKRequestDescriptor *descriptorObject = ...
Custom *object = ...

NSDictionary *parametersForObject = [RKObjectParameterization parametersWithObject:object requestDescriptor:descriptorObject error:nil];

NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parametersForObject
                    options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted //Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                    error:&error];

NSString *jsonString;
if (! jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
}
else {
    jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

I have not find this documented,  I just find it browsing the code, I am not sure if it is a public API or a private one. At least, it works for RestKit 0.20

Comment: RestKit, as i found later, is a very puffacy framework. It has "A LOT OF THINGS" that i do not need, and none of the things that i do need, at least not documented, as you say. I ended up using a different JSON library, and wrote a simple 3 method class to send the request to the server. RestKit also doesnt have (or at least not document) https handling. Which is the main reason i dropped it.

Comment: @LenaBru we use RestKit with https and we don't have any problem. Anyway, I also think at RestKit has a lot of features, and it could be much, much better documented. With some projects it has a lot of overhead and it is not need a library of this size, but for some other projects it can be very useful. As always in the computer world, it depends of the situation.

Comment: Well, i'm sure there is a way to do it. But for a 20MB library, it was hard to find it. I replaced it with a 1.5MB library that does exactly what i need, and not a step more ;) Thanks for your help though, i may need your answer in the future

Answer (score 1):

You generally don't. RestKit serialises to JSON only as part of a network communication. In this case you're converting from an internal to external data format. In your case you want an internal data format stored for a while. In this case it's easier to just use `NSJSONSerialization`. To do this you do need to create a dictionary / array and then use `dataWithJSONObject:options:error:`.

Technically, to do what you ask you would use [`RKMappingOperation`](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKMappingOperation.html). This is done using the `initWithSourceObject:destinationObject:mapping:`, where the source object is the dictionary created from the JSON (`JSONObjectWithData`), the destination object is a new instance of the object targeted by the mapping and the mapping is your mapping to use.

Comment: how ? i am using RestKit 0.20.3 - pls don't send me to the documentation, it has classes that are deprecated in 0.20.3, can you tell me how ? how would i use NSJSONSerialization ?

Comment: please help me, i have looked at several json serializers and deserializers, and all i get is this : +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write'

Comment: Try using JSONObjectWithData instead.

Comment: Added some info. I'm only telling you about classes in the current SDKs.